# Unity Scenes And Asset bundles where not loaded after compiling to APK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Hi can anyone kind enough to share some lights into my problem.
I have existing project and when i run the unity player i have no issue with the game all are working fine.

But when compile to APK i encounter some issue the scenes and assets where not loaded. So what i do is i decompile the APK and found out that the asset folder has no **Assetbundle** folder inside. Now im confuse how this happen i was expecting that upon building all its files suppose to be included. Please advise if anyone encounter this issue.

Below Image When UNITY PLAYER START:
[image]

Below Build Settings:
[image]

Below when installed to phone and run the game:
[image]

Below Assets folder decompile APK:
[image]

Comment: If you want all of your assets in the build then why are you using asset bundles?

Comment: So you mean if asset is build it wont come out as asset bundle upon decompiling apk? because most of  the APK i decompile has assetbundle so i was only curios, but anyways is the anyway i can debug my problem what is the  reason why those scenes not loading .

Comment: Yeah, if you haven't assigned an asset bundle to assets they just get built into the apk. If you see asset bundles in a decompiled apk it's because they were in the StreamingAssets folder which is also built into the apk.

Comment: We build everything but the bare minimum to start the game into asset bundles and then put some of the most frequently used bundles into StreamingAssets until we hit the upload size limit for whatever platform we're building for. That way folks don't need to download those bundles and the game loads faster because they don't need to wait for them to download. If your game is small enough that you can build everything in and you don't need to be able to change the data without uploading a new version to the store then bundles are just extra work for no real benefit.

Comment: In my case why i'm running blank? what options you can recommend for me to debug this.

Comment: How do you load your asset bundle?
And after you build your asset bundle, where is the folder you put it in?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html

Comment: i just found out using adb log cat that the APK upon running is looking for a text file which has the list of path for the asset bundles. It is like a director of assets. at the moment i don't know how to generate asset bundle im still figuring out.

Comment: this the example path inside the TEXT file that im talking about. AssetBundle/actors/baoju/13001/13001_animation-0fb6005a4344dc41c9e8e17f80f6e79d